# SwiftUI: Images in a List are no longer center after adding a .frame maxHeight

Tags: swiftui

I'm displaying a `List` of images, which works fine. They are all centered in the list, but when I add a `maxHeight` the images move to leading instead of center, so I set the alignment to `.center`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```swift
NavigationView {
            List(words, id: \.self) { word in
                NavigationLink(destination: testView(word: word)) {
                    Image(word.imageName)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame( maxHeight: 200, alignment: .center )
                }
            }
        }
```

Has anyone else had this problem and know how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Consider adding more code. Ideally, it should be enough for people to copy, paste and replicate the problem without having to start filling all the gaps.

Comment: Added all the code in the view `body`. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the feedback I received from Apple:

> Engineering has provided the following information regarding this
>   issue:
>
> You need the frame to have an infinite width. This is a layout bug.
>   Please try using a frame with infinite width.

Setting the maxWidth to .infinity did provide a work around for the bug.

For example:

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 250)
```